# C# - Get Exception trying to replace a XmlNode with another

Tags: c#, xml, web-services, soap

I have to work with an old piece of code that calls a **SOAP** web service.
When the service is called, an **assertion** is made and signed with a closed source API that involves smartcard and card reader. This is rather slow.

I have to enhance the functionality : as the assertion has a life time of 60 minutes, I persist it on disk after having generated it and if a new call is made within its lifetime, I want to reuse that assertion instead of generating a new one.

The code is based on the legacy **MS WebService3** framework. I inserted my code in an overrided method called ProcessMessage() that takes a **SoapEnvelope** as an unique parameter where the assertion is generated (a function that calls the smartcard, ask for the PIN code, etc.)

When the assertion is created, I serialize it and write it on disk. Fine.
When a new call is made, if an assertion exists and is valid, I read from disk, and deserialize it.

And here I am with :

- **envelope** : my SOAP document (type SoapEnvelope)
- 2 **System.Xml.XmlNode** :

  - **n2beRemoved** : The Assertion Node from the SoapEnvelope (a placeholder that needs completion)
  - **newAssertion** : The Assertion that has been persisted to disk and read back.

Then I try to replace one node with another in the SoapDocument :

```
XmlNode n2beRemoved = envelope.GetElementsByTagName("Security")[0].LastChild;
n2beRemoved.ParentNode.ReplaceChild(newAssertion, n2beRemoved);
```

When I check (debug) the two nodes they are similar but their parent.

But I got this **Exception** (translated from French): *The node to be inserted comes from a different document context.*

**CONCLUSION**
Thanks to @bommelding, I have found my solution.

*Before*

```
XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();

StreamReader xmlStreamReader = new StreamReader(s_tmpAssertionFile);
xmlDoc.Load(xmlStreamReader);
XmlNode newAssertion = xmlDoc.LastChild;
n2beRemoved.ParentNode.ReplaceChild(newAssertion , n2beRemoved);
```

*After*

```
XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();

StreamReader xmlStreamReader = new StreamReader(s_tmpAssertionFile);
xmlDoc.Load(xmlStreamReader);
XmlNode nImported = envelope.ImportNode(xmlDoc.LastChild, true);
n2beRemoved.ParentNode.ReplaceChild(nImported, n2beRemoved);
```

Thanks again ! :-)

Comment: What do you mean with "similar but their parent." ? That probably is the core problem.

Comment: In debug, n2beRemoved.ParentNode is displayed as {Element, Name="Security"}. This "Security" tag is indeed the parent in my XML doc.

Comment: and newAssertion.ParentNode = {Document}. Sounds OK to me as this is another document and I want to take the node from here and put it instead of n2beRemoved in the other document

Comment: No, that does not sound OK. They have to be owned by the same document.